# How to avoid endless redirection for not logged users in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a function in my wordpress function.php in order to redirect any not logged user to the main page of my site.

Code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && !is_page('http://domain.io/' )  && !is_page('index' ) && !is_page('index.php' )   && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-content/themes/bp-default/begin/intro/index.php' ) {

  wp_redirect( 'http://domain.io/' ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

Works mostly fine but sometimes the redirecction ends in a infinite cycle  and doesn't redirect shows and error connections to the site.

How can I top this infinite cycle?

Comment: Just in case this is not obvious: Don't redirect on the page you redirect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need redirect not logged in users to your home page, You can try this code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_home() ) {
        wp_redirect( get_site_url() ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Without need to set site URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need change the sequence of condition in if.

> !
>   is_user_logged_in() && !is_page('http:// domain.io/' )

change it to

> !is_page('http:// domain.io/' ) && !is_user_logged_in()

Reason for doing this is : 
if  *!is_user_logged_in()*  this condition fails then rest of the conditions will not be checked and user will be redirected to http:// domain.io/, which is your current page, so it will cause the infinite loop as the condition always fail. Changing the sequence of your if conditions should resolve the issue.